# How to linebreak in REGEX with brackets

Tags: regex, adobe-brackets

I got a list of data like exactly like that

```
51.9499, 7.555780000000027; 51.49705, 9.389030000000048; 51.249182, 6.991165099999989; 47.3163508, 11.09513949999996; 51.33424979999999, 12.574196000000029; 50.0297493, 19.196331099999952; 47.8270212, 16.25014150000004;
```

and I want to beautify it a bit by having linebreaks behind the "; " so it would rather look like

```
51.9499, 7.555780000000027; 
51.49705, 9.389030000000048; 
51.249182, 6.991165099999989; 
...
```

I am using Adobe Brackets and I am trying to put a hard linebreak into the replace dialogue but that doesn't work - what would instead work?

Comment: `;\s*` replace with `;\n` - ensure you've selected the `.*` icon in the replace bar to change the replace method to regular expression.

Comment: that'd be worth a real answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the replace bar, click on the `.*` icon to change the replace method to regular expression.

Then you can use `;\s*` replace with `;\n` to *beautify* your code accordingly.

You can see an example of this regex being run [here](https://regex101.com/r/2Rrjs5/1).

Outputs the following:

```
51.9499, 7.555780000000027;
51.49705, 9.389030000000048;
51.249182, 6.991165099999989;
47.3163508, 11.09513949999996;
51.33424979999999, 12.574196000000029;
50.0297493, 19.196331099999952;
47.8270212, 16.25014150000004;
```